# How predict an image in google machine learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-recognition, google-cloud-ml

I'm using Google cloud machine learning. I would like to identify different images.
Now I have trained my model with different type of image (using inception model of tensorflow), and I have created a version in Google machine learning with the results.

How can I get prediction about a new image?
Do you have some idea to help me?

Many thanks!

Comment: would you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite clear on what you're asking.  Without more information, I will just point you to the Google [blog post](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/12/how-to-train-and-classify-images-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow) and [code sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/flowers) that detail how to train on images.

But back to what I think you're asking...for a model to be deployed to Google Cloud ML a few things have to happen:

- It needs to have its inputs and output collections declared in the Tensorflow model before saving the checkpoint.
- The model checkpoint needs to be copied to GCS
- You must use gcloud to create a new "model" (as far as gcloud is concerned, a model is a namespace for many different tensorflow checkpoints) and then deploy your checkpoint to that gcloud model.

The prediction quickstart has a very similar example [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml/docs/quickstarts/prediction).